# Unable to start tweepy tweet scraper from other file

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

my tweepy file works fine. It collects all German tweets.
Now it interrupts sometimetimes. Thus, I want to restart it with another python file. 
The Tweepy file is called "Twython_36" and is started by my Scraper_Starter.py:

```
import threading
def printit():
    threading.Timer(15.0, printit).start()
    print("Scraper restartet.")
    exec(open("./twython_36.py").read())


printit()
```

Now I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 42, in on_status
NameError: name 'langid' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/Scraper_Starter.py", line 10, in <module>
    printit()
  File "C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/Scraper_Starter.py", line 7, in printit
    exec(open("./twython_36.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 263, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 324, in _read_loop
    self._data(next_status_obj)
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 297, in _data
    if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 54, in on_data
    if self.on_status(status) is False:
  File "<string>", line 49, in on_status
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Langid is a library that enables me to scrape German tweets. It is installed.
Why is this code not working, even though if I start my Scraper "Twython_36.py" manually there is no error?

Any suggestions to fix this

Edit: A new error appeared. It asks for a logfile, but this logfile is defined. So I do not see the problem:

```
File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 1180, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/Bachelor_Thesis/Scraper_Starter.py", line 8, in printit
    exec(open("./twython_36.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\M\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 249, in _run
    if self.listener.on_error(resp.status_code) is False:
  File "<string>", line 52, in on_error
N**ameError: name 'logfile' is not defined**
```

Relevant part of the code:

```
**# open log file
logfile = open('twython1.log', 'a')**


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        global old_date
        global writer
        global outfile
        new_date = date.today()
        if not new_date == old_date:
            outfile.close
            outfile = codecs.open ("tweets-" + str(new_date) + ".txt", "ab", "utf-8")
            writer = csv.writer(outfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,lineterminator='\n')
            old_date = new_date
        try:
            lang = langid.classify(status.text)[0];
            if lang == "de":
                writer.writerow( (status.created_at, status.id_str, status.text) )
        except Exception, e:
            # Catch any unicode errors while printing to console
            # and just ignore them to avoid breaking application.
            sys.exc_clear()
#                pass

    **def on_error(self, status_code):
        logfile.write(str(time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )) + ' Encountered error with status code:' + str(status_code) + "\n")
        return True # Don't kill the stream**
```

Comment: Just pitching ideas. But instead of having a Python scripting running 24/7, you could have a cron job.

Comment: As the error says `NameError: name 'sys' is not defined` thus add the missing `import sys`

Comment: thanks. After importing langid and sys it works!